# Persistent sidebar.php

Tags: sidebar, blog

This sidebar does not let itself be aligned either on the left or on the right, so that the content below (the posts) can be placed next to it.

Sidebard on one side, posts on the other.

This is the page: http://www.joaoalexandre.com/wordpressteste/artigos/

And this is the index.php: http://pastebin.com/F9khFceg

Comment: sidebar.php: http://pastebin.com/ye7E6Vqz

Comment: this is more a problem with invalid html and formatting, and not covered by this forum - see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#left
{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
```

It may help you but, it seriously is an HTML and formatting issue.